# Parse.com Js Sdk + Angular pointers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

What if I have an array of events that I want users to be able to rsvp for? Essentially needing the data of the "user" who clicked "rsvp", and the "title" of the "event" that they've rsvp'd for. Could I make a pointer in a Agree class that includes the user's name/id and another pointer that includes the title of the event rsvp'd for? Is there a way to somehow use Angular to add code to the "Agree" class with a form?

**User Class:**

objectId

username

password

**Agree Class:**

objectId

username-(current user)

Comments Structure:

**Event Class:**

objectId-

title-(Need this title)

description-

date-

Please help me understand how to make this work..Thanks!

```
$scope.getAgree = function(){
var Agree = Parse.Object.extened("Agree");
var query = new Parse.Query("Agree");
query.include("userName");


query.find().then(function(results){
  //Go through each in Array
  var rsvpOjectArray = new Array();
  or(i in results){
  //Set Object to current RsvpObject
  var obj = results[i];
  //Get user
  var userName = obj.get("userName").get("username");    


      rsvpOjectArray.push({

                   user: {userName

                   }
           });    
    }
  });
};



$scope.makeAgree = function(){
var Agree = Parse.Object.extend("Agree");
var agree = new Agree();
var user = new Parse.Object("Agree");


agree.set("userName", Parse.User.current());

agree.save(null, {
  success: function(rsvp) {

   // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    alert("success!");
   },
    error: function(rsvp, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the rsvp try                      again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });    
 };
```

Comment: Can you reformat your code & provide class structure which you are using? @user2988188

Comment: Ok I did. Should I have a "rsvp" pointer in my event class?

Comment: Ok maybe users rsvp for an event and I need the event name  to be stored in the user. Would I include a pointer in my user class to the event?

Comment: "Is there a way to somehow use Angular to add code to the "Agree" class with a form?" - It is not related here. 

Also `query.include("userName");` will not work. You have use `query.include("_User");` is you are using USER class of Parse.

Comment: Ok. can you help me with an example that allows users to add objects to a field in the user class when a button is clicked? That would be the ultimate help!

Comment: Here is the example - http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk68fb?p=preview - Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I figured it out!